# Google AppScripts calling doPost() trigger from a server

Tags: html, post, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am facing an unexpected response when I try to call `doPost()` from a server.

Look at the following script:

```
function doPost(e) {
  var params = e.parameter;

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(JSON.stringify(params));
}
```

When I send a POST request to this script, I expect to get `{}` as response. When I use Postman to send a POST request, I get the following response:

```
<!doctype html><html><head><meta name="chromevox" content-script="no"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"><link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/macros/client/css/189396996-mae_html_css_ltr.css"><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/macros/client/js/3229800183-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js"></script></head><body role="main"><table id="warning-bar-table" class="full_size" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td><div id="warning" class="warning-bar"></div></td></tr><tr><td style="height: 100%"><iframe id="sandboxFrame" allow="accelerometer *; ambient-light-sensor *; autoplay *; camera *; encrypted-media *; fullscreen *; geolocation *; gyroscope *; magnetometer *; microphone *; midi *; payment *; picture-in-picture *; speaker *; usb *; vibrate *; vr *" sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation"></iframe></td></tr></table><script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
var el = document.getElementById('sandboxFrame');
el.onload = function() {
goog.script.init("...");}
el.src = 'https:\/\/n--0lu-script.googleusercontent.com\/userCodeAppPanel';
}());
</script></body></html>
```

Looking at this result, it looks like the script is intended to be only run from a browser. But having `doGet()` and `doPost()` makes me suspect that Google wanted such calls to work as well. Could someone clarify what's happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`POST` does work.  You're returning html using `HtmlService`, which, by default, injects Google's load code into the served html. Use [`ContentService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) instead.

```
return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(params));
```